# Ansible Variable Error Deploying Template File

Tags: ansible, ansible-template, ansible-awx

I'm trying to deploy a JSON file as a template and configure the variables for it in a group_var. Here is how I have my ansible structured:

```
inventories > dc > environment > partner_name > group_vars/hosts file > host.yml

└───EWR1
    ├───Prod
    │   └───Partner
    │       └───Candy
    │           └───group_vars
    └───QA
        └───Partner
            └───Tech
                └───group_vars
```

I have a role for this called `candy_deployment` and in that directory I have the following other directories:

- files
- tasks
- templates

In the host yaml, I have the following variables defined:

```
candy_vars:

  price: '5'
  number: '20'
  account: '3fdgdfgFGDfdgdGsdgERgtGERGetgtgTGRT'
  date: '8 Feb 2022 18:00:00 EST'
```

This is what I have for the template file named `candy_deployment.json.j2`:

```
{
    "price": {{ candy_vars.price }},
    "number": {{ candy_vars.number }},
    "gatekeeper": null,
    "solTreasuryAccount": "{{ candy_vars.account }}",
    "splTokenAccount": null,
    "splToken": null,
    "goLiveDate": "{{ candy_vars.date }}",
    "endSettings": null,
    "whitelistMintSettings": null,
    "hiddenSettings": null,
    "storage": "storage",
    "ipfsInfuraProjectId": null,
    "ipfsInfuraSecret": null,
    "awsS3Bucket": null,
    "noRetainAuthority": false,
    "noMutable": false
}
```

When I run ansible in AWX I get the following error:

```
{
  "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'candy_vars' is undefined",
  "_ansible_no_log": false,
  "changed": false
}
```

I'm not 100% on why it's not seeing the variables and I'm a bit lost reading the configs. Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out my own issue. One of the reasons this wasn't working is because the file name I had for the host yaml was different from what I defined in the host file. For example:

```
Original Host File Name: build01-hostname-com.yml



Host Defined in Hosts File: build-hostname-com
```

I needed to change the host yaml file from `build01-hostname-com.yml` to `build-hostname-com.yml` and it was able to see the variables. I also updated the j2 file with `if statements` in case there was an option not there it would give it a default value and not fail. For example:

```
{% if candy_vars.price is defined %}
    "price": {{ candy_vars.price }},
{% else %}
    "price": 0
{% endif %}
```

I did that for each variable I was using/defining. Hopefully this helps someone else with the same issues!